# How to responsive align elements in the header/top nav to the center

Tags: html, css

I am creating a html code that requires a top navigation bar. I have got one already but it doesn't completely show the style I want. I want the top part that says home and about to be centered in the center and the contact us to be on the right side. Currently the top navigation is not responsive. If I am on mobile I want the top nav to have the burger(three line) Icon to be on the right and when the icon is clicked it will have a full screen navigation. Lastly I want the contact us to be aligned. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerlist">
        <h2 id="name">Sprinkler<span id="blue">System</span></h2>
        <div class="top-head">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li id="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

.headerlist {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline;
    width: 99.5%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 6;
    margin: 0px;
}

#name {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    float: left;
    margin-left:180px;
    top: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.headerlist {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 160px;
    width: 98.9%;
    opacity: 0.99;
    z-index: 6;
    padding-top: 20px;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.headerlist ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

.headerlist ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    color: black;
    /* margin-left: 20px; */
    margin-right: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.headerlist ul {
   /*  text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -37.5%; */
}

.headerlist ul a:hover {
    line-height: 1;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

.body {
    margin-left: 180px;
}

.headerlist {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(239, 239, 239);
}

#blue {
    color: rgb(38, 99, 242);
}

.huge {
    font-size:90px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#contact {
    background:blue;
    border-radius:5%;
    padding:10px;
    color:white
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/masonhorder/pen/GLGWXe

Comment: You can use Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#nav) instead of doing it all by yourself.

Comment: @maxime-gélinas i will check it out, i have never used bootstrap and i don't know how it works but i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i try to fix this, using bootstrap:
have a look on codepen.

https://codepen.io/dupinderdhiman/pen/GLGOgN

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the page is responsive, but i want the hamburger icon to pop up instead of the links staying there

Comment: code updated. open codepen in responsive view, you will feel the change

Comment: if works fine, then please upvote the answer, so that next visitor can see the right answer, from up-voted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
//html5

<header>
  <h2 id="name">Sprinkler<span id="blue">System</span></h2>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li id="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
  </nav>
  <div class="icon">=</div>
</header>

// css3

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100px;
}
h2 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none; 
}

.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .icon {
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

// JS
var domElemIcon = document.querySelector('.icon'),
   domElemList = document.querySelector('nav'),
   domElemTitle = document.querySelector('h2') 

domElemIcon.onclick = function() {
  domElemIcon.style.display = 'none';
  domElemTitle.style.display = 'none';
  domElemList.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I don't know if it is what you want, you can try to run and see the results.

Comment: that works but is there a way to make the page have a hamburger icon if it is on mobile? I am not quite getting that from your code. it just resizes the header and does not have the button replace the link.